# Will CSGO "demos" transfer from computers

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

So recently I bought and new PC and I have a ton of matches that I got insane kills on. So I saved them. But when I get my new PC will all the save files be deleted or will I just have to re-download them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell only your last eight matches are available to download from within cs:go.

Matches you downloaded are saved to your local machine and are simply on your harddrive. Of course you can copy those to another harddrive, but you will not be able to download older matches than the last eight matches again.